# thread.QueuedThreadPool in neo4j

Tags: neo4j

I'm using neo4j-community-2.2.3.
neo4J has 2,220,700 nodes and 4,334,748 relations.
Suddenly, neo4j is not working. 
Here is error log in console.log.

```
16:43:04.225 [qtp814955981-22324] WARN  o.e.j.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool -
java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.eclipse.jetty.util.SharedBlockingCallback$BlockerTimeoutException
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.SharedBlockingCallback$Blocker.failed(SharedBlockingCallback.java:184) ~[jetty-util-9.2.4.v20141103.jar:9.2.4.v20141103]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel$CommitCallback.failed(HttpChannel.java:852) ~[jetty-server-9.2.4.v20141103.jar:9.2.4.v20141103]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$1.run(AbstractConnection.java:103) ~[jetty-io-9.2.4.v20141103.jar:9.2.4.v20141103]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:620) ~[jetty-util-9.2.4.v20141103.jar:9.2.4.v20141103]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:540) ~[jetty-util-9.2.4.v20141103.jar:9.2.4.v20141103]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.7.0_80]
Caused by: org.eclipse.jetty.util.SharedBlockingCallback$BlockerTimeoutException: null
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.SharedBlockingCallback$Blocker.block(SharedBlockingCallback.java:216) ~[jetty-util-9.2.4.v20141103.jar:9.2.4.v20141103]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpOutput.write(HttpOutput.java:133) ~[jetty-server-9.2.4.v20141103.jar:9.2.4.v20141103]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpOutput.close(HttpOutput.java:163) ~[jetty-server-9.2.4.v20141103.jar:9.2.4.v20141103]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Response.closeOutput(Response.java:1017) ~[jetty-server-9.2.4.v20141103.jar:9.2.4.v20141103]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:421) ~[jetty-server-9.2.4.v20141103.jar:9.2.4.v20141103]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:248) ~[jetty-server-9.2.4.v20141103.jar:9.2.4.v20141103]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:540) ~[jetty-io-9.2.4.v20141103.jar:9.2.4.v20141103]
        ... 3 common frames omitted
16:43:04.226 [qtp814955981-22324] WARN  o.e.j.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool - Unexpected thread death: org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3@74989b47 in qtp814955981{STARTED,1
2<=28<=28,i=0,q=1466}
16:43:04.227 [qtp814955981-22351] WARN  o.e.j.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool -
java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.eclipse.jetty.util.SharedBlockingCallback$BlockerTimeoutException
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.SharedBlockingCallback$Blocker.failed(SharedBlockingCallback.java:184) ~[jetty-util-9.2.4.v20141103.jar:9.2.4.v20141103]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel$CommitCallback.failed(HttpChannel.java:852) ~[jetty-server-9.2.4.v20141103.jar:9.2.4.v20141103]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$1.run(AbstractConnection.java:103) ~[jetty-io-9.2.4.v20141103.jar:9.2.4.v20141103]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:620) ~[jetty-util-9.2.4.v20141103.jar:9.2.4.v20141103]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:540) ~[jetty-util-9.2.4.v20141103.jar:9.2.4.v20141103]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.7.0_80]
Caused by: org.eclipse.jetty.util.SharedBlockingCallback$BlockerTimeoutException: null
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.SharedBlockingCallback$Blocker.block(SharedBlockingCallback.java:216) ~[jetty-util-9.2.4.v20141103.jar:9.2.4.v20141103]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpOutput.write(HttpOutput.java:133) ~[jetty-server-9.2.4.v20141103.jar:9.2.4.v20141103]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpOutput.close(HttpOutput.java:163) ~[jetty-server-9.2.4.v20141103.jar:9.2.4.v20141103]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Response.closeOutput(Response.java:1017) ~[jetty-server-9.2.4.v20141103.jar:9.2.4.v20141103]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:421) ~[jetty-server-9.2.4.v20141103.jar:9.2.4.v20141103]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:248) ~[jetty-server-9.2.4.v20141103.jar:9.2.4.v20141103]
```

Please, advise! Many thanks in advance!

Comment: is it happening when you start the database or when there are some operations on it ?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you have exceeded the maximum number of threads available to the web server to handle requests. As you submit queries that query occupies a web server thread until such time as it returns or times out. IF you have a lot of queries that take a while to run you can run out of threads. The number of threads available to the http server is configurable. See [the server browser configuration documentation](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/server-configuration.html#server-browser-config):

> Specify the number of threads used by the Neo4j Web server to control
>   the level of concurrent HTTP requests that the server will service.
>
> org.neo4j.server.webserver.maxthreads=200

However, if this is frequently happening you probably need to look more closely at why your queries are taking so long to execute or your overall server load.